# fadeIn onLoad function

Tags: javascript, html, fadein

So, Im trying to get this id to fade in on the load of the page.  I've seen the posts about fade in.  However, I haven't found any related to an onLoad function.  Could anyone help me out with this?

HTML:

```
 <div id="intro"> HELLO, I AM </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$( "#intro" ).onLoad(function() {
  $( "#intro" ).fadeIn( "slow")
});
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such jQuery function as `onLoad`. Also, you'll probably want to set the default display of your element to "none" using CSS. And, as @Andreas commented, you would then put the `$.fadeIn()` call in a `$(document).ready()` callback, so it only executes once the DOM is loaded. So, all together now:

HTML:

```
<div id="intro"> HELLO, I AM </div>
```

CSS:

```
#intro {
  display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#intro").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks so much!